# Azure equivalent for logon script or Group Policy to launch programs on user login

Tags: group-policy, entra-id, azure-networking, logon-scripts

We have a tool (portable exe) that runs from an on premises server in a traditional domain that launches on user login via GP (and can also run from logon script).  It references a location on the domain server in the traditional manner of \server\folder\app.exe.

Azure is basically inevitable and Microsoft, as far as I've been able to determine, has no transition document for that. It's vast and written to assume we should know a lot that we don't.

What's the path to that?  And yes, spent days reading the vast MS docs online - too much geared to prior knowledge and zero to "So, you're new in these parts."

Comment: Logon to what in Azure? A portal? A VM ? Azure Virtual Desktop Session? But I think it's important to think in a cloud native way, and for example when you want to apply policies when a user logos on to Azure you can use Azure Conditional Access. Leave the on-premise world behind a bit and use the cloud native services.

Comment: Very judgemental comment that does not address the question.  On-premises domains return a local IP as well as a domain name, like company.local.  Azure of any kind does not.  Checking the registry is not clear-cut.  A home (not business) user can have O365 and show they are on an Azure network, but that's not the same as a corporate network, e.g. AD joined etc.

If there's a way to weed out home users vs. actual business users using Azure *domain*, that's what I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no equivalent unfortunately. The endpoints management capabilities we have with Azure are nowhere near as advanced as what we're able to do with GPO.

So, you'll have to "DIY": Create a script that registers a scheduled task that runs at logon to start the tool you want. Then, use Intune to [deploy the Script to the devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/apps/intune-management-extension).

Comment: The Lord giveth, the Lord taketh away.  Progress, I guess.